# Use distinct keyword with two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

I want to take unique values using DISTINCT keyword. I have two more tables.

Table Names:

- (T1)Cand_details

  Locationofwork
- (T2)requirement_details

  Locationofposting

I want to select these two table values by using keyword distinct. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Locationofwork, Locationofposting FROM Cand_details, Locationofposting
```

You should relate both tables with common fields if they have.

Answer (score 3):

```
select LocationOfWork
  from cand_details
 union
select Locationofposting
  from requirement_details;
```

A `UNION` operator serves to combine data from **multiple SELECT statements**.

In this case, without the **ALL** keyword (`UNION ALL`), the `UNION` operator includes a `DISTINCT` function which will give you the unique locations across both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Locationofwork as "LOC" 
From Cand_details 
UNION Select Locationofposting as "LOC" 
FROM requirement_details
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is easily possible. You can encapsulate as many feilds as you like in the distinct ( ) clause.